# Error using Retrofit Builder in Android app: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method metafactory

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit, openweathermap

I am trying to get current weather from an API, and for some reason, when I am trying to create a Retrofit object, it returns me an error:

```
    Process: com.api.weather_api_training, PID: 8417
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite; in class Ljava/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory' appears in /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar)
        at okhttp3.internal.Util.<clinit>(Util.java:87)
        at okhttp3.internal.Util.skipLeadingAsciiWhitespace(Util.java:321)
        at okhttp3.HttpUrl$Builder.parse(HttpUrl.java:1313)
        at okhttp3.HttpUrl.get(HttpUrl.java:917)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.baseUrl(Retrofit.java:506)
        at com.api.weather_api_training.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.api.weather_api_training"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'


}
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.api.weather_api_training;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView temperatureTextView;
    private TextView humidityTextView;
    private TextView windSpeedTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        temperatureTextView = findViewById(R.id.temperatureText);
        humidityTextView = findViewById(R.id.humidityText);
        windSpeedTextView = findViewById(R.id.windSpeedText);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.openweathermap.org/")                                    // Error is here
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        WeatherServiceAPI weatherServiceAPI = retrofit.create(WeatherServiceAPI.class);

        Call<List<WeatherClass>> weatherCall = weatherServiceAPI.getWeather();

        weatherCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<WeatherClass>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<WeatherClass>> call, Response<List<WeatherClass>> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    WeatherClass weatherClass = (WeatherClass) response.body();

                    System.out.println(weatherClass.getCurrentWeather().getHumidity());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<WeatherClass>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

WeatherServiceAPI:

```
package com.api.weather_api_training;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public interface WeatherServiceAPI {

    @GET("data/2.5/onecall?lat=50.0412&lon=21.9991&exclude=hourly,daily&appid=(my id)")
    Call<List<WeatherClass>> getWeather();
}
```

Of course, in (my id), I put in my id from the website.
Is there any way to fix that error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59448917/4364824) you need to switch to Java 8 compatibility

```
android {

   ...
   compileOptions {
       sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   }

   kotlinOptions {
       jvmTarget = "1.8"
   }
}
```