# Android studio fatalerror

Tags: android, sdk, android-gradle-plugin

I tried running build program in my Android studio 4.0. it is just an hello world app but the app keeps crashing
This is the Logcat file

```
what is the issue  2023-09-03 01:47:48.353 22534-22534/com.victory.beehive E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    Process: com.victory.beehive, PID: 22534

    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite; in class Ljava/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory' appears in /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar)

        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.<init>(ComponentActivity.java:142)

        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.<init>(FragmentActivity.java:103)

        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.<init>(AppCompatActivity.java:96)

        at com.victory.beehive.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:7)

        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)

        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)

        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)

        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1253)

        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3383)

        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3678)

        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)

        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)

        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)

        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2106)

        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)

        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)

        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7943)

        atwhat is the issue  2023-09-03 01:47:48.353 22534-22534/com.victory.beehive E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    Process: com.victory.beehive, PID: 22534

    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite; in class Ljava/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory' appears in /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar)

        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.<init>(ComponentActivity.java:142)

        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.<init>(FragmentActivity.java:103)

        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.<init>(AppCompatActivity.java:96)

        at com.victory.beehive.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:7)

        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)

        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)

        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)

        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1253)

        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3383)

        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3678)

        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)

        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)

        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)

        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2106)

        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)

        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)

        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7943)

        at
```

My dependencies

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'

androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
```

I use Gradle 6.1.1 sdk platform 31 , Gradle plugin 4.0.0, buildsdk 31.0.0, minsdk 26, targetsdk 31

I was excepting it to show hello world but it keeps crashing. I am new to this so I am quite lost.
Pls any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

I think the most important park of your stack trace is the first part that says:
no static method meta factory, so I found this other question that has this answer:

[No static method metafactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59448845/no-static-method-metafactory)

Try to switch to Java 8 compatibility mode, for proper de-sugaring of some library:

```
android {

    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
         jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```